# Trying to JOIN columns from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have one table (city_data) with the columns 'year', 'city_name' and 'avg_temp'. The other table is global_data and has the columns 'avg_temp' and 'year'. I am trying to create a table which has the average temperature of London, the global average temperature for all the years. 
My SQL code is the following:

```
SELECT city_data.avg_temp, city_data.year
FROM city_data
JOIN global_data
ON city_data.year = global_data.avg_temp
WHERE city= 'Paris'
```

I get no error but cannot get the expected result. I think I am not able to understand what I need to put in the ON clause.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  For instance, do you want the result *per year* or over all the data.  And if your SQL code starts with `FROM`, you have a problem.  Queries start with `SELECT`.

Comment: There probably no city with an average temparature > 1900 degrees. Join on *year* instead

Comment: HI, I forgot to paste the select statement, but I have edited it now

Comment: Please answer Gordon's question. Do you want *one* result row (with the average temperatures through all the years) or do you want *several* result rows (one for each year)?

Comment: And what is your DBMS? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ... If MySQL, which version?

Comment: Hi, I want 3 columns one for the temperature in London, the other with the global average temperature and the other with all the years. I basically want one row per year. My DMBS is MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the table `global_data` has one row per year, while `city_data` has one row per year and city. This means you can simply join the two on the year they have in common:

```
select year, g.avg_temp as global_average, c.avg_temp as paris_average
from global_data g
join city_data c using (year)
where c.city = 'Paris'
order by year;
```

If you don't like to join the two and only then mention Paris, you can also turn this into:

```
select year, g.avg_temp as global_average, p.avg_temp as paris_average
from global_data g
join (select * from city_data where city = 'Paris') p using (year)
order by year;
```

As of MySQL 8 you can even use a `WITH` clause to "prepare" Paris :-)

```
with paris as (select * from city_data where city = 'Paris')
select year, g.avg_temp as global_average, paris.avg_temp as paris_average
from global_data g
join paris using (year)
order by year;
```

Or consider Paris a join criteria:

```
select g.year, g.avg_temp as global_average, p.avg_temp as paris_average
from global_data g
join city_data p on p.year = g.year and p.city = 'Paris'
order by g.year;
```

As you see, there are many ways to write the same query and the DBMS would probably come up with the same execution plan for all. So, just pick the query you like best.

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helped! I had never seen the 'USING' clause before!

Comment: Sometimes `USING` comes handy, but you can always use an `ON` clause instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM city_data
JOIN global_data
ON city_data.year = global_data.year
```

-- it should be `global_data.year` in Join

```
WHERE city= 'Paris'
```

Comment: Hi you are right. However, when I execute this, I get a table with only 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

This is completely based on the partial understanding

```
SELECT city_name, AVG(city_data.avg_temp) as global_avg
    FROM
    city_data
    JOIN global_data
    ON city_data.year = global_data.year
    WHERE city_name = 'Paris'
    GROUP BY city_data.city_name
```

Answer (score 0):

As `year` is the only common attribute, join using it. Then fetch the city average table as it is readily availble in the `city_data`. Lastly do the avg for `global_data`, as you want to fetch it across years.

```
SELECT `city_name`, `city_data`.`avg_temp` AS city_avg_temp, AVG(`global_data`.`avg_temp`) AS global_avg_temp
    FROM `city_data`
    JOIN `global_data` 
        ON `city_data`.`year` = `global_data`.`year`
    WHERE `city_name` = 'London'
    GROUP BY `city_data`.`city_name`
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, you are correct to tell me to rename certain columns. When executing this code, I get the following message: column "city_data.avg_temp" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: That's correct. Otherwise it throws the ambiguous column name error.